# After Installing Ubuntu 14.10 on a Dell Dimension 4600 x-86, Ubuntu Is Running Very, VERY Slow

Tags: dell, 14.10

I installed Ubuntu 14.10 on a Dell Dimension 4600 (Pentium 4 2.80 512 RAM) that was running Windows XP.  Windows XP ran fine.  Now with just Ubuntu 14.10 installed, everything (minimal - just software that came with 14.10) is running very slow.

I decreased the swappiness from 60 to 10 but it didn't appear to make a difference.

Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?  If not, is there a better release of Ubuntu to use?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

With that age of a machine you need to go to an older, lighter OS. With only 1/2GB of RAM you should use **Lubuntu** or **Xubuntu**, because the full Ubuntu needs more RAM and your experience will not be great. Also use UNetBootin to make a bootable USB then test/install from there.

Comment: Thank You.  I will download and install one of them.  I really appreciate you quick response.